# Java Abstract Class Constructor Scope

Tags: java, abstract-class

I was wondering what would be the best way to approach this problem:

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestClass
{
    public AbstractTestClass(String text)
    {
        SomeObject someObject = SomeStaticClass.getSomeObjectFromText(text);
        //etc...
        this.property1 = someObject.property1
        //basically populate properties based off of someObject
    }
}
```

And an example implementation:

```
public class AbstractTestClassImpl
{
    public AbstractTestClassImpl(String text)
    {
        super(text);
        SomeObject someObject = SomeStaticClass.getSomeObjectFromText(text);
        //do stuff with someObject that isn't done in the super constructor because it may vary per different implementations of the abstract class
    }
}
```

So from this example code snippet, someObject is created twice, and I was wondering if its possible to just create it once or to just leave this as is.

The obvious solution would be to make `someObject` a member variable in the AbstractClass, however, I also have the case where `someObject` is not required at all.

Consider the constructor:

```
public AbstractTestClass(int i, int j, char c)
{
    //do stuff where someObject is not required
}
```

In this case, it would not make sense to have a `someObject` member since its not used at all.

Assume that `someObject` is only used in that one constructor.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: What is the problem with having `someObject` as an instance member even if you dont use it all the time?

Comment: That's part of my question I guess. I'm not sure if its good practice to do that.

Comment: on the other hand it almost sounds like the class is not abstracted enough if you need two completely separate constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have the static factory method, you can return the same object for each call to the static factory method with the same text. If you can't do that, you could either make a protected instance variable or have a protected contstructor that takes a `SomeObject` parameter and only makes a new one if the parameter is null. The subclass can make the `SomeObject` and pass it to the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest smell in your code is calling a static class inside a constructor instead of passing the value into the constructor as a parameter. What I think would help the most is asking

How can I test this?

Look into writing some unit tests in JUnit. PowerMockito provides the capability to mock static classes but in this scenario it wouldn't provide an effective test because the test code would have to understand the code instead of understanding the behavior.

I really enjoy this article [Write Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf) and occasionally reference it myself.

Comment: Well think of `String text` as `filename`. I want to create an instance of an object by just passing the filename. 

The static object is simply a static function that creates an instance of an object and calls a function that belongs to the newly created. I could easily just copy paste that, but I decided to include the static function because it means that my object doesn't have to know too much about what the static call is doing.

Actually in retrospect, calling it a static class is wrong. I should edit that.

Comment: That is my point. The object won't have any knowledge of the static class if the resulting value is passed in as a parameter. I can't tell if you are creating POJOs or translators without seeing more code. Regardless, testing will help with the design.

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on design, but given you have to do what you mentioned above, here is what i would suggest:

Move code from abstract class into init method which returns reference for object, in implementation class call init method of abstract class, use returned reference to do extra processing.

Hoping this solves your problem.

Cheers !!